# Ethereum Transaction: why balance does not change after transaction?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I set up Ethereum private chain, opened two accounts, mined some ethers in the first one. However, when I tried to send 1 ether from one account to the other, the balance did not change. The snapshot is as following.
[Transaction does not change balances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdUUR.png)
Any one has a clue to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't stop the miner. Transactions will only be credited to the accounts (i.e., the *state* will only be changed) if a transaction is included in the block.

So if you run a private network for testing purposes, keep always a miner running. One mining node with a single miner thread is sufficient:

```
geth --mine --minerthreads=1 [your custom options]
```